# Laravel Array Generar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

tengo este código y se me complica generar un array.

En la consulta actual con un var_dump me genera esta respuesta, pero yo necesito que estén agrupadas para poder incrustarlo en otro código.

```
        string(8) "IPhone X"

        string(12) "Spectre x360"

        string(11) "Mac AirBook"
```

Lo que necesito es poder obtener valores de tipo array como estos:

```
array( 
"name" => "IPhone X", 
"etc"  => "etc", 
),
array( 
"name" => "Spectre x360", 
"etc"  => "etc", 
),
array( 
"name" => "Mac AirBook", 
"etc"  => "etc", 
),
```

Este es mi Código

```
 @foreach($ezpos_product_sale_data as $product_sale_data)
        @php $ezpos_product_data = \App\Product::find($product_sale_data->product_id); 

        $eprod = $ezpos_product_data->name;

        $data = $ezpos_product_data->name;  


        @endphp 



    {{ $data  }}



    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa lógica no debería estar en la vista, no hay un motivo por el cual realizar consultas a la base de datos desde ahí.

En todo caso, lo más sencillo sería tener el array de id primero y luego sí realizar la consulta, para eso vamos a utilizar el método pluck en la colección inicial y posteriormente obtenemos esos productos:

```
$productIds = $ezpos_product_sale_data->pluck('product_id');

$ezpos_product_data = \App\Product::whereIn('id', $productIds)->get()->toArray();
```

En caso que necesites más información, revisa la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck

Comment: Me me genera este error [2019-04-25 15:39:31] local.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65028096 bytes) {"userId":1,"email":"admin@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65028096 bytes) at C:\\xampp\\htdocss\\prototipo\\storage\\framework\\views\\81ac4f65f29877ed3c7fcd3507a76d974247ff0b.php:58)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}

Comment: Eso quiere decir que  probablemente la consulta es muy grande para la cantidad de memoria (asumo). Eso ya es un problema aparte de optimización de los recursos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer lo que te explicó Shaz, debes poner ese código en la controller y mejor en un fichero Repository. 
Luego de hacer el whereIn() debes llamar al metodo ->get() y despues toArray() y obtendrás lo que estás buscando.

Quedaría de esta forma.

```
$ezpos_product_data = \App\Product::whereIn('id', $productIds)->get()->toArray();
```

con get() devuelves el collection asociado al query conformado y toArray() devuelve el collection transformado a array.

Comment: Con esto me viene joya, muchas gracias. 
Pero ahora tengo otra duda, como haría para filtrar datos, con un var_dump a  $ezpos_product_data me muestra todos los datos pero quisiera solo tomar algunos y poder ejecutar un "AS" sobre algunos de ellos pero no estoy ni cerca de saber como hacerlo.

Comment: Que bien que te sirvió. Primero var_dump no es para filtrar datos, sirve para mostrar datos en pantalla mientras se hace el desarrollo, aunque exsiten muchos mas como un dump, dd, log. Me podrias explicar con mas detalles que deseas filtrar y que entiendes por "AS". La paralabra reservada `as` se usa para porner alias a los campos, tablas, consultas en codigo sql en general.